# Drawing a point/line in gtk. C++

Tags: c++, gtk, mouse, point

Hey I am using c++ to write a program which has a drawing area. I need to make it possible to detect mouse signals from the drawing area and draw points at these positions. How can I do this? There are not many forums which help with this stuff and the documentation is not clear. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Are you using GTK 2 or GTK 3 ? GTK 2 uses the `expose-event` event, whereas GTK 3 uses the `draw` event. Are you using the GTKmm (GTK C++ bindings), or the GTK C API in your C++ program ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drawing in a gtk3 application is done in response to the "draw" signal. You connect a callback function to the "draw" signal, and when gtk+ needs to redraw the window, your callback is invoked.

```
g_signal_connect (drawingarea, "draw",
                  G_CALLBACK (draw_cb), NULL);
```

The callback looks something like this:

```
static gboolean
draw_cb (GtkWidget *widget,
         cairo_t   *cr,
         gpointer   data)
{
  // do your drawing on the provided cairo_t
  // ...

  return FALSE;
}
```

Now, to handle mouse clicks, you'll need to connect another callback function to "button-press-event":

```
g_signal_connect (drawingarea, "button-press-event",
                  G_CALLBACK (button_press_event_cb), NULL);
```

See the [drawing area reference docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html) for a small example and the [drawing area demo](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/demos/gtk-demo/drawingarea.c) for a complete application.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gtkmm](http://gtkmm.org) with C++, it's the best option.  Most events can be captured by overloading a particular virtual method.  For a mouse press, you overload the `on_button_press_event` method.   The tutorial at gtkmm.org is not too bad (for open source tutorials that is), you can get a good start by reading about the basics and look at  other chapters of interest as needed.